# Populating array (by 'name') in array of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

Lets say i have an array of arrays, of which i dont know the names, just that they are arrays, and how many of them there are.

```
bigArray=[smallArrayA[], smallArrayB[]]
```

Now i can fetch the array(s) by indexposition, like:

```
smallA = bigArray[0]
smallA << 'input'
```

But what i'd like to know is the names of the arrays, stored in the 'big' one..

```
bigArray.inspect
```

..just gives me:

```
[['input'],[]]
```

My problem is that the names of the smaller ones are going to be created dynamiclly, and i need to know their names to modify the right one, later on.

Comment: What do you mean by name? An array in ruby has only indexes, not 'names'... Maybe what you're looking for is a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html)?

Comment: A Hash is absolutely more suited, yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a hash:

```
bigHash = { :a => smallArrayA, :b => smallArrayB }
```

Now you can refer to each element of the hash by name:

```
bigHash[:a]
```